# Convert string to JSON object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string in this format:

```
var abc = "{'ABC':'25117', 'data':'India\"NewDelhi\"'}"
```

I want to convert this to a JSON object.

I've tried to use `""` and `''` by interchanging them.

I've used the function `JSON.parse(abc)`, it works if the string

```
var abc = '{"ABC":"25117", "data":"India\'NewDelhi\'"}'
```

But I want that `"NewDelhi"` should be in double quotes i.e. `""` and this is my strict condition.

Comment: Your strict condition means that the string you have is not valid JSON, and it can't be converted. Though luck, either drop that silly condition or create your own parser for you invalid format.

Comment: That JSON isn't valid. Use [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick with valid JSON, and just double escape the quotes

```
var abc = '{"ABC":"25117", "data":"India\\"NewDelhi\\""}';
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/se0mzhe6/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape "\" to be able to parse your string.

```
var abc = "{\"ABC\":\"25117\", \"data\":\"India\\\"NewDelhi\\\"\"}"
```

Then `JSON.parse(abc)` will works